# Refreshing an Access Token vs obtaining a new one

Tags: powershell, azure, oauth, access-token

I am writing a some PowerShell scripts to log into Azure AD using a clientid/secret.

The code for obtaining a new access / refresh token is very simple. I have a Get-Token function with all the error checking etc in about 80 lines of code.

If I write Get-Token so that it will decide whether to get a new token, send an existing one or to obtain a new one with a refresh token would invariably be considerably more complex.

Is there any benefit to renewing tokens rather than simply obtaining a new one each time the function is called? (considering there is no consumer side to this, it is a backend script to connect to Azure services)

**ETA**

This isn't using ADAL, it is using raw HTTP requests, so I'm managing the tokens directly.